# mapping bytes produces int but single element bytes object is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Mapping a bytes type with the following lambda

```
unpack = lambda val: struct.unpack("!b", val)[0]

list(map(unpack, b'\xb1\xbb\n\x0f'))
```

gives the error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) says

> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object b, b[0] will be an integer, while b[0:1] will be a bytes object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1)

which explains why an int is passed. So if i would manually loop over the bytes object, i could access the elements with `[x:x+1]` instead of with `[x]`.

My question now would be if there is a way to make map produce bytes object of length 1, so that the unpack function gets what it expects.

I found that this works

```
unpack = lambda val: struct.unpack("!b", bytes(bytearray([val])))[0]
```

but it seems like an ugly workaround to me. Is there a better, more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more concise way doesn't exist yet from what I'm aware. [A proposition](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/#abstract) has been made but it's still a draft.

You still have some other options in order to make it appear more friendly, though. For example, a little generator that produces bytes:

```
def iterbytes(b):
    for n in range(len(b)):
        yield b[n:n+1]
```

or, similarly but probably slower:

```
def iterbytes(b):
    for i in b:
        yield bytes([i])
```

Then wrap the bytes object in this `iterbytes` generator:

```
list(map(unpack, iterbytes(b'\xb1\xbb\n\x0f')))
```

---

Since you wrap `map` in `list`, i.e you're after a list, I'd probably go with a comprehension instead of a `map`:

```
>>> b = b'\xb1\xbb\n\x0f' 
>>> [unpack(b[i:i+1]) for i in range(len(b))]
[-79, -69, 10, 15]
```